# How to test ASP.NET Core Web API with cookie authentication using Postman?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application (.NET Core 2.1) that implements Cookie Authentication as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
});
```

The web application also includes a web API where client-side JavaScript makes Ajax calls back to the web server. The web API controllers are decorated with `[Authorize]`; requiring the user to login via the web application before the Ajax calls can access the web API methods.

I want to use Postman (Windows native application) to test the web API calls while running the web application on localhost. How do I copy the authentication cookies into Postman from the browser after logging in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To copy cookies from the browser to Postman, you'll need to use the Browser's Developer Tools and Postman's Manage Cookies feature.

1. Run and log into your web application and open the Browser's Developer Tools.
2. From Developer Tools, locate the list of cookies for localhost. Using Chrome (version 73) as an example, select the Application tab and expand the Storage > Cookies option.
3. From the Cookies option, click on your localhost web application e.g. http://localhost:port. This will display the list of cookies.
4. Having logged into your web application, a cookie named `.AspNetCore.Cookies` should be present. Copy the value i.e. it should be a long string of characters such as `CfDJ8FNwIhImGGFJmGnb...`
5. From Postman, create a request to access your chosen web API method and locate the Cookies option for the request.
   Example from Postman (v7.0.6) below: 
   [image: Postman (v7.0.6) Cookies option screenshot]
6. From within Manage Cookies, add a new cookie. Example from Postman (v7.0.6) below:

   [image: Postman (v7.0.6) Adding Cookie from Manage Cookies screenshot]
7. The placeholder value should be updated from:

   > Cookie_1=value; path=/; domain=localhost;

   to

   > .AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8FNwIhImGGFJmGnb...*shortened for brevity*...; path=/; domain=localhost;
8. Click send. The response should be the data or error returned from the web API method call and not the HTML of your login page. If it's the login page HTML, then the cookie or cookie value is most likely incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how authentication with an API works. You need to send an `Authorization` header with some sort of token. You'd generally have a centralized identity provider that can handle multiple authentication schemes. The web application would actually authenticate with this identity provider via client credentials and request the API scope. You'd then be provided a token that authorizes that web application to work with the requested API. You pass the token in the `Authorization` header with your requests and then the API would verify the token with the identity provider to ensure that it's a valid token granting access. The identity provider described above can be IdentityServer or a hosted solution like Auth0 or Azure AD.

Regardless, you do not authorize via a cookie. Cookies are for web applications. APIs are stateless and therefore don't have cookies. The cookie exchanged from the web application to the browser would not work for the API anyways, as they're not the same thing.

Comment: This post wasn't about how authentication with an API works. It was steps to get Postman to work when you are working with an API that uses cookie authentication alongside MVC app, regardless of whether it's right or wrong. Re. "cookie exchange... would not work for the API", follow the steps and it works.